# Can't resolve the reference 'UIKit.UINavigationBarAppearance'

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am getting following error while building the app after updating the xamarin forms version to 4.5.0.356

I am not getting why this happening after updating the version.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'UIKit.UINavigationBarAppearance', referenced from the method 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer::UpdateBarBackgroundColor()' in 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'.
```

Answer (score 3):

`UINavigationBarAppearance` was added in iOS 13.0.

So update your Xamarin.iOS version, and Xcode version, to at least Xamarin.iOS 13.x.x.x and Xcode 11.x